# How to split my data into train, validation and test datasets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm using a flowers dataset which has this structure:

[image]

I have already split this data into training and validation sets and my network is running based on these 2 sets. I split the data into a 80:20 split, 80 for training and 20 for validation. I want to have a data split so it is 80 training, 10 validation and 10 test. My code is here:

```
import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=dataset_url,
                                   fname='flower_photos',
                                   untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
```

```
#Loader params
batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180
```

```
#Training imgs
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

```
#Validation imgs
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

I'm wondering how I can alter this code to add a testing set to test my network using model.evaluate() from tensorflow. I thought of taking images from the folders before creating the train/validation sets but can't figure it out or if there is an easier way.

Comment: Did you follow the keras tutorials? Or read the docs? They tell you how to do this.

Comment: You can use tf.keras.utils.split_dataset function, to split valid_ds to get test_ds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [tf.keras.utils.split_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/split_dataset) API available in Tensorflow 2.10 to split the dataset to train and test sets like below

```
train_ds,test_ds=tf.keras.utils.split_dataset(
    train_ds, left_size=None, right_size=.2,
)
```

Kindly refer to this [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/98947851a776f66b3e045da25cd2f9a7/74257284.ipynb#scrollTo=5QWUaXTmK30a) for working code. Thank you!